# Aggregate with a limit in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions

In this query, each row of table `a` could have hundreds of rows of table `b` associated with it. So the `array_agg` contains all of those values. I'd like to be able to set a limit for it, but instide `array_agg` I can do `order by` but there's no way to set a limit.

```
select a.column1, array_agg(b.column2)
from a left join b using (id)
where a.column3 = 'value'
group by a.column1
```

I could use the "slice" syntax on the array but that's quite expensive since it first has to retrieve all the rows then discard the other ones. What's the proper efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I would use a lateral join.

```
select a.column1, array_agg(b.column2)
from a left join lateral 
    (select id, column2 from b where b.id=a.id order by something limit 10) b using (id)
where a.column3 = 'value'
group by a.column1
```

Since the "id" restriction is already inside the lateral query, you could make the join condition `on true` rather than `using (id)`.  I don't know which is less confusing.

Comment: I think I understand but I'm still trying to wrap my head around LATERAL joins. Could you also please show the subquery equivalent so I can understand how they relate to each other?

Comment: I just realized, don't you need to sort the results in the `array_agg` again? Doesn't it need to be `array_agg(b.column2 order by b.something)` instead, or was the `order by something` in the subquery guaranteed to preserve the order in the "outer" query?

Comment: @user779159 . . . This doesn't set a limit per `column1`.  It sets a limit per `id`.  That is different from what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to count first and then aggregate:

```
select a.column1, array_agg(b.column2)
from (select a.column1, b.column2,
             row_number() over (partition by a.column1 order by a.column1) as seqnum
      from a left join
           b 
           using (id)
      where a.column3 = 'value'
     ) a
where seqnum <= 10
group by a.column1
```

Comment: The answer using a LATERAL join looks a bit clearer to understand. Is there a reason this one would be better or is it a matter of preference?

Comment: @user779159 . . . The lateral join doesn't do the same thing.  This allows you to control the number of rows in the final result.  The lateral join only allows you to control the number per `id`, not per `column1`.  I think this is more in the spirit of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

In many cases you can create an array from a subselect using the [ARRAY keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ARRAY-CONSTRUCTORS) (near the bottom of the linked heading).

```
select a.column1, ARRAY(select column2 from b where b.id = a.id limit 10)
from a
where a.column3 = 'value'
group by a.column1
```